# BAT file that runs SQL and then prints databases list

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I am trying to make a BAT file that opens up MYSQL and pipes out Databases to a text file.
Please and thank you.

```
::BAT file that opens up MYSQL and pipes DATABASES into a text file.
::20190330
::JimmyWilliams
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls
Echo Opens up MYSQL and shows databases
pause
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
mysql -uJames -p****** 
SHOW DATABASES; > C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\test.txt
pause
```

Comment: http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/mysql/Run-mysql-Commands-from-Batch-File.html  
I am wondering if it is possible to have all the commands within a single BAT file, or do you have no choice except  to have a BAT file and a TXT file?

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered the answer:

```
::20190330
::JimmyWilliams
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls
Echo Opens up MYSQL and shows databases
pause
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
mysql -uJames -p****** -e "SHOW DATABASES;" > C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\test.txt
pause
```

How Can I remove the "password warning prompt"?